# iPhone app with different languages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to know how to add more languages to my app. My app allows user to choose different languages on settings tab, but is there any way different as multiply views by number of languages?

This assuming a multilanguage app but, can an app be submitted on app store with different languages? In this case, user will choose desired language to download! possible?? Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about having a language selector if you follow the internationalization guides, your app will use the appropriate language file based on their device's language settings.

Comment: Not only that, but you explicitly shouldn't have a language selector in your app. You should follow Apple's internationalisation guidelines so that your app simply starts up in whatever language people have their phone set to.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide fully localized version of application to App Store

If you need to change UI layout, elements position, you can do it
see this: http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/

see also:
http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial